# Focus on one div and disable the others around

Tags: html

I am using a master layout for my website. But on one of the pages, I want that only the content in main div appears focused while others are disabled; just like in jquery popup. Is there a way to achieve this

Comment: Can you provide some more details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not completely clear what is your goal here. If I tried to disable all **controls** on the page except ones on you main div, I would probably end up with some javascript:

```
<body onload="desableControls()">
...
<div id="mainDiv">
...

<script type="text/javascript">
    //disable everything
    $("input").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    //enable controls on your main div
    $("#mainDiv input").removeAttr("disabled");
</script>
```